# Custom arrow style for matplotlib, pyplot.annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, customization, annotate

I am using matplotlib.pyplot.annotate to draw an arrow on my plot, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.annotate("",(x,ybottom),(x,ytop),arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
```

I want to use an arrow style that has a flat line at one end and an arrow at the other, so combining the styles "|-|" and "->" to make something we might call "|->", but I can't figure out how to define my own style.

I thought I might try something like

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches                                                                                                                                                                              
myarrow = patches.ArrowStyle("Fancy", head_length=0.4,head_width=0.2)
```

(which should just be the same as "->" for now; I can tweak the style later) but then how do I tell plt.annotate to use myarrow as the style? There is no arrowstyle property for plt.annotate, and arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle=myarrow) doesn't work either.

I've also tried defining it in the arrowprops dictionary, such as

```
plt.annotate("",(x,ybottom),(x,ytop),arrowprops=dict(head_length=0.4,head_width=0.2))
```

but that gives me errors about no attribute 'set_head_width'.

So, how can I define my own style for pyplot.annotate to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the last example in your code you could have used `headwidth`, `frac` and `width` to customize the arrow, the result is `arrow0` shown below. For highly customized arrows you can used arbitrary polygons. Below you can see the code I used to produce the figures.

To add more polygons you have to edit `polygons` dictionary, and the new polygons must have the first and the last point at the origin `(0,0)`, the rescaling and repositioning are done automatically. The figure below illustrates how the polygons are defined.

[image]

There is still an issue with shrinking that disconnects the line with the polygons. The '|-|>' arrow that you requested can be easily created using this customization.

[image]

The code follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import transforms
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin
plt.close()
plt.plot([1,2],[0,4], 'w')
ax = plt.gcf().axes[0]

def patchesAB(styleA, styleB, orig, target,
                widthA, lengthA, widthB, lengthB,
                kwargsA, kwargsB, shrinkA=0., shrinkB=0.):
    '''
    Select 'styleA' and 'styleB' from the dictionary 'polygons'
    widthA, lengthA, widthB, lenghtB, shrinkA, shrinkB are defined in points
    kwargsA and kwargsB are dictionaries
    '''
    polygons = {\
        '|':np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[0.1,1],[0.1,-1],[0,-1],[0,0]], dtype=float),
        'arrow1':np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[-1,2],[3,0],[-1,-2],[0,-1],[0,0]], dtype=float),
        'arrow2':np.array([[0,0],[-1,1],[0,2],[3,0],[0,-2],[-1,-1],[0,0]], dtype=float),
               }
    xyA = polygons.get( styleA )
    xyB = polygons.get( styleB )
    #
    fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = fig.axes[0]
    trans = ax.transData
    pixPunit = trans.transform([(1,0),(0,1)])-ax.transData.transform((0,0))
    unitPpix = pixPunit
    unitPpix[0,0] = 1/unitPpix[0,0]
    unitPpix[1,1] = 1/unitPpix[1,1]
    #
    orig = np.array(orig)
    target = np.array(target)
    vec = target-orig
    angle = np.arctan2( vec[1], vec[0] )
    #
    lengthA *= unitPpix[0,0]
    lengthB *= unitPpix[0,0]
    widthA  *= unitPpix[1,1]
    widthB  *= unitPpix[1,1]
    orig   += (unitPpix[1,1]*sin(angle)+unitPpix[0,0]*cos(angle))*vec*shrinkA
    target -= (unitPpix[1,1]*sin(angle)+unitPpix[0,0]*cos(angle))*vec*shrinkB
    #TODO improve shrinking... another attempt:
    #orig   +=  unitPpix.dot(vec) * shrinkA
    #target -=  unitPpix.dot(vec) * shrinkB
    # polA
    if xyA != None:
        a = transforms.Affine2D()
        tA = a.rotate_around( orig[0], orig[1], angle+np.pi ) + trans
        xyA = np.float_(xyA)
        xyA[:,0] *= lengthA/(xyA[:,0].max()-xyA[:,0].min())
        xyA[:,1] *=  widthA/(xyA[:,1].max()-xyA[:,1].min())
        xyA += orig
        polA = patches.Polygon( xyA, **kwargsA )
        polA.set_transform( tA )
    else:
        polA = None
    # polB
    if xyB != None:
        a = transforms.Affine2D()
        tB = a.rotate_around( target[0], target[1], angle ) + trans
        xyB = np.float_(xyB)
        xyB[:,0] *= lengthB/(xyB[:,0].max()-xyB[:,0].min())
        xyB[:,1] *=  widthB/(xyB[:,1].max()-xyB[:,1].min())
        xyB += target
        polB = patches.Polygon( xyB, **kwargsB )
        polB.set_transform( tB )
    else:
        polB = None
    return polA, polB

# ARROW 0
plt.annotate('arrow0',xy=(2,1.5),xycoords='data',
             xytext=(1.1,1), textcoords='data',
             arrowprops=dict(frac=0.1,headwidth=10., width=2.))
#
kwargsA = dict( lw=1., ec='k', fc='gray' )
kwargsB = dict( lw=1., ec='k', fc='b' )
# ARROW 1
orig = (1.1,2.)
target = (2.,2.5)
shrinkA = 0.
shrinkB = 0.
polA, polB = patchesAB( '|', 'arrow1', orig, target, 20.,1.,60.,60.,
                        kwargsA, kwargsB, shrinkA, shrinkB )
ax.add_patch(polA)
ax.add_patch(polB)

ax.annotate('arrow1', xy=target, xycoords='data',
             xytext=orig, textcoords='data',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-', patchA=polA, patchB=polB,
                 lw=1., shrinkA=shrinkA, shrinkB=shrinkB, relpos=(0.,0.),
                 mutation_scale=1.))
# ARROW 2
orig = (1.1,3.)
target = (2.,3.5)
polA, polB = patchesAB( '|', 'arrow2', orig, target, 20.,1.,60.,60.,
                        kwargsA, kwargsB, shrinkA, shrinkB )
ax.add_patch(polA)
ax.add_patch(polB)

ax.annotate('arrow2', xy=target, xycoords='data',
             xytext=orig, textcoords='data',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-', patchA=polA, patchB=polB,
                 lw=1., shrinkA=shrinkA, shrinkB=shrinkB, relpos=(0.,0.),
                 mutation_scale=1.))
plt.autoscale()
plt.xlim(1.,2.2)
plt.ylim(0.5,4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What about adding a flat endcap to the tail? Like this: |------>

Comment: Thanks. I certainly wouldn't call that "easy", but it does the job. Luckily the issues with perspective and shrink don't come up in the context I'm using it.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is it completely bananas that this sort of thing isn't built into matplotlib?