# How to get the exact shrink value when customizing arrow styles in annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, customization, annotate

When willing to use customized arrow styles in `matplotlib` one can do the approach explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17009403/832621). But there is still an issue when `shrinkA` or `shrinkB` are specified.

I thought of a way to calculate these values using `matplotlib` functions, but without success, doing:

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches

orig = (1.1,2.)
target = (1.1,3.)
shrinkA = 10. # given in points
shrinkB = 0.
b = patches.ConnectionStyle('arc')
path = b.connect( orig, target )
path = b._shrink( path, shrinkA, shrinkB )
```

But nothing happens with `path` when I do that... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach was quite correct, it seems that `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` should be given in a ratio value between `0.` and `1.`:

```
orig =   (1.1,2.)
target = (1.1,7.)
shrinkA = 0.1 # given in points
shrinkB = 0.1
b = patches.ConnectionStyle('Arc')
path = b.connect( orig, target )
path = b._shrink( path, shrinkA, shrinkB )
```

To get the new values for `orig` and `target`:

```
neworig, newtarget = path.vertices
```