# Matplotlib circle as arrowhead

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am working on a plotting tool for graphs and want to use use circles as arrowheads for FancyArrowPatch when connecting to nodes, like this:
[image] Also I would like to allow three different styles: "o--o", "o--" and "--o".

*Is there is a generic way to use Patch objects as arrowheads?*

My alternative approach would be to use small circle patches and manually plot them on top of the edges right before the nodes. But this would include calculating the correct coordinates when dealing with curved edges which I would like to avoid. I have already read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968007/custom-arrow-style-for-matplotlib-pyplot-annotate), but as far as I understand it, the solution won't work with FancyArrowPatch.

Thanks in advance.