# Is it possible in Python to create a custom made polygon and use that as arrow to produce a stream plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i want to create a plot with 13 different arrow styles for a vector field showing the stream of a sea. I want to use very specific arrows which are not bult in FancyArrowPatch. Is ther a possibility to use a selfmade design as arrow in python ? Is it possible to somehow add custom arrow styles to the FancyArrowPatch function ?
I have attached the image I want to reproduce with Python (taken from  bsh.de/DE/DATEN/Stroemungen/stroemungen_node.html):
[image: This Image was taken from bsh.de/DE/DATEN/Stroemungen/stroemungen_node.html]

My best try was to produce this one:
[image]

Which is not quite satisfying yet. I would like to have the same arrows as seen in the first image. If you have suggestions how to make the image fancier I am open for that too.

Comment: what is so special in your arrows? Did you check documentation for [FancyArrowPatch](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html) and common elements? Did you see demo [connection style](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/userdemo/connectionstyle_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-connectionstyle-demo-py)

Comment: I basically want to copy the arrows on the following website : https://www.bsh.de/DE/DATEN/Stroemungen/stroemungen_node.html

Comment: I used the FancyArrowPatch already and know the common elements. I did not find a way to create a custom made arrow eg. as a polygon and use it as an arrow style.

Comment: you could add this link to question - more people may see it and better understand problem. You could even add image which shows these arrows. At this momen only idea is to use [Polygon](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html). Eventually I would dig in [source code](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/_modules/matplotlib/patches.html#FancyArrowPatch) to see how works FancyArrowPatch and if I could copy code and create own class for Arrows.

Comment: I used Google "matplotlib add polygon arrows" and I found interesting ideas: [Custom arrow style for matplotlib, pyplot.annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968007/custom-arrow-style-for-matplotlib-pyplot-annotate/) and [How to draw an arrow that loops with Matplotlib](https://naysan.ca/2020/07/04/how-to-draw-an-arrow-that-loops-with-matplotlib/)

Comment: I added the link, the image I want to reproduce and the image I have made so far. The problem of not the exact arrows i need remains.